# Packaging issues in the attempting to run a maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a common problem in maven but I'm not able to figure out how to fix it. Maybe the solution is in front of my eyes.

This is a common and well-know problem in developing maven project

I have an eterprise application composed of

```
ear
war
ejb
```

When I try to run it I got this error. Sorry but my glassfish is in my own language and I don't know how to change it. I should reinstall it but I can't. I will loose all my settings... I found out a solution to this problem which say I should  not add to WAR project EJB and infact my war POM.xml is the following:

**WAR POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>volaconnoi-webapp-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
            <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EJB XML**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
    volaconnoi-webapp
    it.volaconnoi
    1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
<artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-ejb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>volaconnoi-webapp-ejb</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**EAR POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>volaconnoi-webapp-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
            <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
            <artifactId>volaconnoi-webapp-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you may see ejb is provided. but despite that I got always this error. How can I fix it? Tell me what informations you need to help me. I will be very glad to provide them to you

```
Grave:   Eccezione durante la distribuzione dell'applicazione [volaconnoi-webapp-ear] : Impossibile risolvere il riferimento [Remote ejb-ref name=it.volaconnoi.bean.GetterFidelityPointsBean/utilBean,Remote 3.x interface =it.volaconnoi.logic.UtilBeanInterface,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] perché sono presenti [2] EJB nell'applicazione con l'interfaccia it.volaconnoi.logic.UtilBeanInterface. 
Di seguito sono riportate alcune delle cause possibili. 
1. La classe di bean EJB è stata inclusa nel package di una libreria EAR LIB (o mediante altro meccanismo di libreria che rende la libreria visibile a tutti i moduli dei componenti). Pertanto tutti i moduli dei componenti includono indirettamente questa classe di bean. 
2. La classe di bean EJB è stata inclusa nel package di un modulo di componente che fa riferimento all'EJB, direttamente o indirettamente mediante il file manifest, WEB-INF/lib. 
La classe di bean EJB deve essere inclusa solo in un package del modulo EJB di dichiarazione e non nei moduli di riferimento. I moduli di riferimento devono includere solo interfacce EJB.
```

Comment: This is my similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189937/maven-doesnt-recognize-ejb-as-dependency-of-project-when-trying-to-define-modul

Comment: Well, did you try the answer to that (duplicate) question?

Comment: Yes sure...as you may see I posted my war pom.xml and provided scope is added as well

Comment: But `<type>ejb</type>` is in the answer, and it's not in what you posted.

Comment: yes you're right...I'm going to add it and check if it works...

Comment: always the same...nothing has been changed

Comment: I can post all the three pom.xml if this could help you

Comment: Ok I have right now fixed the issues or it seems so...I removed ejb from ear dependency

Comment: My question is: the ear project need as dependency EJB?

Comment: In this example EAR uses ad dependencies war and ejb https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html